# Set value to Input type number not working correctly

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to set a value to input type `number` using Jquery. It's not working when the length of value is more than 15 characters.

Here is my sample code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("button").click(function(){
        $("#user").val(11111111111111444444444888888888);
    });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<p>Name: <input type="number" id="user" ></p>
<button>Set the value of the input field</button>
</body>
</html>
```

The result is:

> 11111111111111400000000000000000

It is unexpected for me. Why does it become zero after 15 characters? It is working fine when the length of the number is less than 15. I tried to use the `min` and `max` attribute, but this isn't working either.
Any idea?

Comment: 1. the value you try to paste is an exponential value, not a number.2. Unable to reproduce your problem:- https://jsfiddle.net/3bkz6vat/

Answer (score 1):

I think this is because javascript numbers are always 64-bit floating point.

Unlike many other programming languages, JavaScript does not define different types of numbers, like integers, short, long, floating-point etc.

JavaScript numbers are always stored as double precision floating point numbers, following the international IEEE 754 standard.

Examples:

```
var x = 999999999999999;   // x will be 999999999999999
var y = 9999999999999999;  // y will be 10000000000000000
```

Explication and example gathered from [W3Schools](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_numbers.asp).

Maybe you can add `''` to the `val()`in order to pass the value as a string.

Answer (score 0):

As Goediaz has the explanation of this behaviour,
You may want to put it in `val()` as a string.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("button").click(function(){
        $("#user").val(11111111111111444444444888888888);
        console.log("Number:", $("#user").val());
        $("#user").val("11111111111111444444444888888888");
        console.log("String:", $("#user").val());
    });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<p>Name: <input type="number" id="user" ></p>
<button>Set the value of the input field</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: @SadeghAlinejad I've just checked and I got the same output on Chrome and Firefox. But, I've got Firefox 59.0.2… Why don't you update your browser? :)